# Deploy Laravel and Angular local with apache

Tags: php, angularjs, apache

I am using Laravel and angular. My app works with artisan serve command on localhost:8000

If i want to deploy locally without using artisan command I copied to var/www/html/ and run localhost/project/public it works.

My landing page is login and it routes with `localhost/project/`
But I click the link on the landing page i get 404 not found with url `localhost/project/login`.

I found a way with `localhost/project/index.php/login`. this works but my angular ng-view is blank.

How to make laravel with angular work without php artisan serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use something like a .htaccess rule to tell Apache to strip out `index.php` from the URL.

I've used the following on previous projects:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

EllisLab (creators of CodeIgniter framework) also have a good guide on this: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html

Comment: its already set in .htaccess for me. The landing page works for me but from there links are not working

Comment: I didnt enable mod_rewrite in apache. I realized it after seeing you answer. So i accept it.